# When I use the "textdraw" in Blender 2.8, it fills the object or bleeds all over the surface. How can I correct this problem?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm using blender 2.8 to make a head of a girl and am at the texture painting stage.  I have the image of the texture made and saved.  The object has been switched to flat and I am trying to paint the skin color on it.  The textdraw will not paint strokes.  It either fills the whole object or bleeds all over the whole surface.  Please help me fix this problem as I am a semi-beginner. Thanks

Some of the meshes are overlappimg and the uv map does not really look like the object.  How can I correct this?

Comment: What does your uv map look like? If it is all of the mesh faces on top of each other, then that would explain the paint dabs quickly acting like a Fill tool.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) If you have further details your should edit your post and add more information to it, and address or answer any comments by other users